# Run only one pipe at a time

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying to do service with multiple methods - each method will return pipe. The only one method can be called at a time; otherwise, the switch of pipe should happen.

This is an example of how I achieved it -- https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3pry8u?devtoolsheight=60 . It looks too complicated and has a potential memory leak, but it works. If you will try to click fast "Make red"/"Make green"/"Make blue" buttons, only the last will be triggered(see the console.log).

As requirement - it is important to control pipe run inside Color, not outside. I can imagine how it can be solved with the outside way: I could merge all click events to one pipe and use switchMap(). But it is interesting for me - how this problem can be solved properly inside Color class.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to solve it inside `Color` class:

I didn't use `switchMap` as I'm not going to make use of inner observables. I did get rid of `makeRed`, `makeGreen` and `makeBlue` functions as well.
I merged all the events and applied `debounceTime` to them.

```js
Color
 .mergeEvents (events: Observable<any>[]) {
    merge<State>(...events)
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
    )
    .subscribe(c => {
      console.log(c)
      this.state$.next(c);
    })
  }
```

```js
const color = new Color();

color.mergeEvents([
  fromEvent(document.getElementById("make-red"), "click").pipe(mapTo({ color: 'red' })),
  fromEvent(document.getElementById("make-green"), "click").pipe(mapTo({ color: 'green' })),
  fromEvent(document.getElementById("make-blue"), "click").pipe(mapTo({ color: 'blue' })),
]);
```

[Here is a StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7rmi2k?file=index.ts).